# Openssl stops working when generating pkcs#12 with friendly name

Tags: windows, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

I'm currently working on generating a certificate & private key and trying to import it in a pkcs#12 file, however when i try to generate it, i had a error from OpenSSL. For my tests, i have to insert a friendly name to my privatekey when the p12 is generating. Here under some details :

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12 -name "otto"
```

After this last command, i enter the server.key passphrase, enter an export password, and after that, a window appears informing that OpenSSL crashed...

I already searched for solutions, but found nothing usefull, does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you for your help

Regards

Comment: Which version of openssl do you have ? (openssl version)

Comment: I'm using v0.9.8h on Windows. I just tried recently with v1.0.1e on CentOs and it seems to work ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.